$p(z)$ polynomial with $p(0) \neq 0 \neq p(1)$; $\int_{\partial R} \frac{p(z)}{(z-1)z^2}dz$; $R=[-1,2] \times [-1,3]$

Consider $p(z)$ a polynomial such that $p(0) \neq 0 \neq p(1)$ and the rectangle $R=[-1,2] \times [-1,3]$, calculate $\int_{\partial R} \frac{p(z)}{(z-1)z^2}dz$

The poles $P=\{0,1\}$ are in the interior of $R$ and by residues' theorem, we have:
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\partial R} \frac{p(z)}{(z-1)z^2}dz \\[8pt]
=&2\pi i\Big(res\Big(0,\frac{p(z)}{(z-1)z^2}\Big)+res\Big(1,\frac{p(z)}{(z-1)z^2}\Big)\Big)\\[8pt]
=&2 \pi i\Big(\frac{p'(0)(0-1)-p(0)}{(0-1)^2}+\frac{p(1)}{1^2}\Big)\\[8pt]
=&2\pi i\Big(-p(0)-p'(0)+p(1)\Big)
\end{align*}
Is this calculation correct given the hypothesis above?

This isn't a question about physics, you'd probably get a more satisfactory response on [math.se].

I think the term $p(0)$ should carry a factor of $-1$ in the last two lines. That is the minus sign in the numerator of the formula $(\frac uv)' = \frac{vu' - uv'}{v^2}$ -- you have used a plus sign in the numerator.
